# Provide open/save option when pdf opens in browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, pdf-generation

when my user clicks a link i'd like to provide the standard open/save dialog for the pdf, instead of opening it in the browser...using the ffg code to generate the pdf:

```
 Document document = new Document();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        try
        {
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
            pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;

            document.Open();
            document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
        }
        catch (DocumentException de)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(de.Message);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ioe.Message);
        }

        document.Close();

        stream.Flush(); 
        stream.Position = 0; 
        return File(stream, "application/pdf");
```

Comment: just a guess but Response.AddHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + attachment.AttachmentName() + "\"" );   along the lines of that, so rather than deliver content of type PDF, you create an attachment of PDF and this prompts the user to save or view

Answer (score 1):

Try providing a name to the file when returning it by using the third argument of the `File` method:

```
return File(stream, "application/pdf", "report.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Document document = new Document();
    FileStream stream = new FileStream("report.pdf", FileMode.Create);
    try
    {
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
        pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;

        document.Open();
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
    }
    catch (DocumentException de)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(de.Message);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(ioe.Message);
    }

    document.Close();

    stream.Flush(); 
    stream.Position = 0; 
    return File(stream, "application/pdf");
```